# WPF theme/templates using WIndows Store Apps theme/templates

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

**Scenario:** All of the users are on Windows 7 and we develop windows desktop apps, i.e. WinForms and WPF. I really enjoy the Win8 Store Apps UI/UX and would like to bring that into our WPF apps.

**Questions:**

1. I was wondering if anyone has attempted to do this type of effort, i.e. bring some of the themes/templates from the WinStore Apps into WPF?
2. Or are there any resources out there that can give some guidance, e.g. blogs, articles, code, etc?

Comment: Are you looking for [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/)?

Comment: @HighCore - That toolkit is one of two I came across, the other being MUI WPF from CodePlex. Though they are both "modern", they don't really resemble the Win8 Store Apps I've come across, either out of the box in Visual Studio or the Store. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: If MahApps or MUI doesn't work for you - you could check out some commercial component providers (see list at the bottom [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)) or creating your own templates. It shouldn't be too hard since the modern style is quite minimalistic, but it is quite a bit of work to change all the templates you use.

Comment: Thanks @FilipSkakun for the feedback and I've come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

MahApps and Elyseum open source projects are excellent resources.